# Numerical solution for an infinite integration with no explicit solution in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I want to have a numerical result for this equation:

[image]

But it consists of infinite integration with no explicit solution. Should I solve the integral pointwise to get my result?

I want to use the `syms` function in MATLAB at first, but the final result is also an implicit result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you put any assumptions on f? Can you assume f(x) is nonnegative?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer but an extended comment as I a not going to include any specific MATLAB code.

I assume that `\nu` is a positive value. Under the condition that f(x") > 0 for all x", the function under the outer integral becomes very close to zero outside of a small neighborhood of x because exp(-y^2) is almost zero outside of a small neighborhood of 0.

So you can assume that the limits of the integral are (x - A; x + A) for some positive A. You can choose A so that this approximation is within your desired precision.